# Image sizes in html signature in Mac Mail can't be fixed

Tags: html, email, html-table

I found [this post](https://www.daretothink.co.uk/html-email-signature-in-apple-mail/) where it is explained how to create a nicely looking email signature within Mac Mail. After following the instructions, I managed to locate the signature file. I figured Mac Mail includes images encoded in the same file using base64 encoding. So once I edited the file with a table, everything looked great on Mac Mail. However, when I send the emails I got huge images, even though I had specified the `width` and `height` properties of the images in the table. I couldn't figure out why mail clients (both Mac Mail and Mail for iOS) chose to ignore the sizes of images, so I was left with no choice but to reduce the size of the images so they appear with the correct number of pixels. This now works ok when I open the signature in Mac Mail, but it still shows really bad in iOS:
[image]

I have the feeling that I'm making silly mistakes in the html code. Is there a way to force that the table occupies 100% of the width irrespective of the device where I open it, and that each of the columns occupies a fixed percentage of this width? Also, is it possible that I use high-resolution images (bigger images) without changing the appearance of the signature? This is the code I have, except for the encoded images:

```
Message-Id: <E7A4C1FD-32C3-4CC0-902B-CDF3A26F9804>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 13.0 \(3608.60.0.2.5\))
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="Apple-Mail=_BBC3233F-4323-4ACF-A4B4-7BB0ECFE542E"


--Apple-Mail=_BBC3233F-4323-4ACF-A4B4-7BB0ECFE542E
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=utf-8


    <p style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">
        <table style="width: 650px" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="10pt" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td vAlign="middle" style="width:260px"><SPAN class=3D"Apple-string-attachment"><OBJECT height=3D45 width=3D255 =
type=3Dapplication/x-apple-msg-attachment =
data=3D"cid:part1.3D429B4D.FBA99AB0@dress-sinpalabras.com"></OBJECT></SPAN=
><span class=3D"Apple-tab-span" style=3D"caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); =
color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; =
font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; =
letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: =
0px; text-transform: none; white-space: pre; widows: auto; word-spacing: =
0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; =
text-decoration: none;">    </span><span style=3D"caret-color: =
rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: =
12px; font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: =
normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; =
text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: =
auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; =
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration: none; display: inline =
!important; float: none;"> </td>
    <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; width: 390px; padding-left: 20px; border-left: #000000 1px solid" vAlign="top">
    <strong style="font-size: 11pt">
    <span style="font-size: 11pt; color: #000000">JULIA BIRLING</span> | Founding Director</strong><br><br>
      <a href="http://dress-sinpalabras.com">www.dress-sinpalabras.com</a><br>
        <a href="mailto:jbirling@dress-sinpalabras.com">jbirling@dress-sinpalabras.com</a><br><br>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dress.sinpalabras/"><SPAN =
class=3D"Apple-string-attachment"><OBJECT height=3D40 width=3D37 =
type=3Dapplication/x-apple-msg-attachment =
data=3D"cid:part4.1A5B7902.C522684D@dress-sinpalabras.com"></OBJECT></SPAN=
></a>&nbsp; 
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sinpalabras_dress/"> <SPAN class=3D"Apple-string-attachment"><OBJECT =
height=3D40 width=3D39 type=3Dapplication/x-apple-msg-attachment =
data=3D"cid:part6.A712535C.3060744F@dress-sinpalabras.com"></OBJECT></SPAN= >= </a></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </p>


--Apple-Mail=_BBC3233F-4323-4ACF-A4B4-7BB0ECFE542E
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename=it.png
Content-Type: image/png;
    name="it.png"
Content-Id: <part6.A712535C.3060744F@dress-sinpalabras.com>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon sending, Mail.app converts that `<object>` into an `<img>` and strips its height and width attributes.

Try adding a `<style>` tag to prevent the image from growing larger than its container, something like:

```html
<style><!-- img { max-width: 100%; } --></style>
```